# Why the feature of persisting user login is not available in flutter by default?

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

When we work on firebase and flutter we need to do additional things for persisting user login. I think this should be available by default. Is there any reason for not making it available by default?

Answer (score 1):

Firebase and Flutter actually do have a persisting user login feature inbuilt:

```
Future<void> _checkUser() async {
    Auth _auth = Auth();

    if (await _auth.isLoggedIn()) {
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
           context, MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => HomeScreen(),
                          ));
    } else {
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
           context,MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => LoginScreen(),
                          ));
    }
  }
```

Though we recommend using [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) for this because it stores a bool (true for Logged In/ false for Logged Out) and can be fetched without using internet which makes our app load in an instant.